# How to install WE8EBCDIC500 on Oracle XE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I need to make the "WE8EBCDIC500" character set available in an Oracle XE installation (on my desktop) to import a mainframe-generated file.

Running `SELECT value FROM v$nls_valid_values WHERE parameter='CHARACTERSET'` does not show this character set to be installed and I get `KUP-03006: error initializing handle for character set WE8EBCDIC500` when attempting to use it.

How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EBCDIC is not on the list of supported character sets published in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/files/install.102/b25144/toc.htm#BABBBIBE) for XE.